# Image upload issue

Tags: image, upload

Having issues uploading images. This is the error I get.

> Warning: move_uploaded_file() [function.move-uploaded-file]: Unable to move '/tmp/phpoQGOIB' to '/home/bermoent/public_html/img/tmp/PSVmdBmY' in /home/bermoent/public_html/admin820/tabs/AdminProducts.php on line 1088

1. An error occurred during the image upload

Running Magento version 1.7

Comment: are you uploading file using input type file html element?

Answer (score 0):

Make sure the upload directory /home/bermoent/public_html/img/tmp/PSVmdBmY exists and is writable (write permission). If no, create directory and set write permission.

Best of luck!

Comment: Aren't these directories generated dynamically?